# Which Encryption Method Is Being Used in My OpenVPN server?

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, openvpn, encryption

When I try connecting to my OpenVPN server , the log on OpenVPN software is a bit confusing .

```
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
```

Is the data being encrypted in DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA ?

Here is my client .ovpn file content :

```
persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
pull

verb 3

auth-user-pass
```

here is my server.conf file on the VPS :

```
port 1194 #- port
proto udp #- protocol
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
reneg-sec 0
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
#plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 5 30
persist-key
persist-tun
status 1194.log
verb 3
plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
```

so my question is : " what encryption method is being used here ? "

I see :

```
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Encrypt: **Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key**
Fri Nov 19 04:16:29 2021 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMA
```

and then :

```
Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 **DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA**, 1024 bit RSA
```

I want to use the lowest encryption method possible as I want higher speed and less data usage . If there is anyway I can improve the speed and have a faster connection , please let me know .

BTW , OpenVPN server version is 2.4.11 .

Answer (score 1):

There is two differents things here :

###### SHA1

The Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA) is used to authenticate data and SSL/TLS connections. In this process, a unique fingerprint is created to validate the TLS certificate – that is, to check you’re connecting to the server you’re supposed to be. Without this, a hacker could re-route your traffic to their own server instead of your VPN provider’s

###### The cipher

Encryption ciphers are at the heart of VPN technology. They help determine how the secure tunnel is formed. Each cipher offers a different solution to secure, private and anonymous browsing.

###### Warnings

Be carefull using SHA1, because the algorythm is not enought secure now. You should use a better algo, like SHA512 for the handshake.

###### Conclusion

Your VPN encryption's algo is `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`

I recommand you to [read this](https://www.analyticsinsight.net/the-comprehensive-guide-to-vpn-encryption-ciphers/) :)

Comment: thanks for the information . they were very useful . for speed purposes , I need to reduce encryption level . Do you know how to reduce encryption level in OpenVPN server 2.4.11 ? Perhaps to something like DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA . I tested different parameters in server.conf and also the ovpn file but didn't achieve anything .